# KnockoutJS intercept to one decimal place

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I know variations of this have been asked, but my requirement is that instead of formatting/rounding the value that's entered, I need to not even allow the user to enter more than one number after the decimal point. I have something that works with a decimalFormatter binding handler, but it's clunky - i.e., it allows you to enter a value like '20.' and you can't erase all the values due to the way I have the regular expression written. I realize I could modify that to accept optional digits for the whole entry, but what I really want is for it to revert to 0.0 if the user erases the value. And, allow for them to enter '20.' then tab out (onblur) and have it reformat the value to 20.0 so it looks more complete. Currently, if the user enters '20.' then saves the form, it does store a whole value of 20, and when you reopen/retrieve the value from the database, it shows 20.0 so it looks fine when reloading.

I thought about adding an onblur event but we don't want to do that in overriding what has been databound by knockout. We want to keep everything bound by the ko view model, so that's not an option. I've also seen some suggest a computed observable (for example this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19714921/knockoutjs-value-binding-with-restriction)) but my binding already does that. On second thought, would the knockout [event binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html) be the way to go here???

html:

```
<input style="width:38px" data-bind="decimalFormatter: percentage"/>
```

javascript:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.decimalFormatter = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var initialValue;

    //$(element).on('keydown', function (event) {
    $(element).keydown(function (event) {
        initialValue = $(element).val();

        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
        if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 ||
        // Allow: Ctrl combinations
        (event.ctrlKey === true) ||
        // Allow decimal/period
        (event.keyCode === 110) || (event.keyCode === 190) ||
        // Allow: home, end, left, right
        (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
            // let it happen, don't do anything
            return;
        }
        else {
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105)) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });

    $(element).keyup(function (event) {
        if (!$(element).val().match(/^\d+\.?\d?$/)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(element).val(initialValue);
        }
        else
            return;
    });        

    var observable = valueAccessor();

    var interceptor = ko.computed({
        read: function () { return formatWithComma(observable(), 1); },
        write: function (newValue) {
            observable(reverseFormat(newValue, 1));
        }
    });

    if (element.tagName == 'INPUT')
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { value: interceptor });
    else
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { text: interceptor });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    }
}

// Formatting Functions
function formatWithComma(x, precision, seperator) {
    var options = {
        precision: precision || 2,
        seperator: seperator || '.'
    }
    var formatted = parseFloat(x, 10).toFixed(options.precision);
    var regex = new RegExp('^(\\d+)[^\\d](\\d{' + options.precision + '})$');
    formatted = formatted.replace(regex, '$1' + options.seperator + '$2');
    return formatted;
}

function reverseFormat(x, precision, seperator) {
    var options = {
        precision: precision || 2,
        seperator: seperator || '.'
    }

    var regex = new RegExp('^(\\d+)[^\\d](\\d+)$');
    var formatted = x.replace(regex, '$1.$2');
    return parseFloat(formatted);
}

var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.percentage = ko.observable(20.0);
};

var vm = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sfortner/nmku6wx6/)

Comment: Curly braces are out of balance.

Comment: fair enough - fixed. I usually pull code out of Visual Studio, paste into Textpad, tab everything over, then replace the tab with four spaces to meet the SO requirement of code indented four spaces. Is there an easier way?

Comment: I do similar in Notepad++, which color-codes the text making it simple to match opening/closing brackets and to spot typos in variable names etc etc. Maybe Textpad does the same but I've not used it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: lol, would you believe we've got meta.stackexchange.com blocked here at work? : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well i used `AUTONUMERIC` plugin for number formatting which was reliable and awesome .

I just made a sample fiddle to your requirement check it [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/9z26k1qb/)

**View Model:**

```
var vm = function(){   
this.Amount=ko.observable(""); 
this.OnloadAmount=ko.observable(143); //onLoad Test
ko.bindingHandlers.autoNumeric = {
       init: function (el, valueAccessor, bindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
            var $el = $(el),
              bindings = bindingsAccessor(),
              settings = bindings.settings,
              value = valueAccessor();

            $el.autoNumeric(settings);
            $el.autoNumeric('set', parseFloat(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value()), 10));
            $el.change(function () {
                value(parseFloat($el.autoNumeric('get'), 10));
            });
        },
        update: function (el, valueAccessor, bindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
            var $el = $(el),
              newValue = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
              elementValue = $el.autoNumeric('get'),
              valueHasChanged = (newValue != elementValue);

            if ((newValue === 0) && (elementValue !== 0) && (elementValue !== "0")) {
                valueHasChanged = true;
            }

            if (valueHasChanged) {
                $el.autoNumeric('set', newValue);
            }
        }
    };
}

  ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

**View :**

```
<input type="text"  data-bind="autoNumeric:$data.Amount, settings:{mDec:1,aSep: ''} " />
```

Here `mDec:1` restricts number to decimal palce of one and `asep:''` means it will not sperate number with commas etc

**PS:** we can restrict entering invalid characters and do lots of other stuff with ease .

For complete Reference check [**here**](http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/)

Comment: that's super cool, sc! Thanks for the help. Looks like it works perfectly with no drama. Nice..

Comment: glad it helps . explore more options(if necessary) its a wonderful plugin .

Comment: Actually, I had been using the super-small 4KB accounting.js library (http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/), but pretty sure it doesn't do everything we need easily to match the features of autonumeric to build this binding handler. Rather than use two libraries I will look into it to see if I can retool your bindingHandler to possibly use accounting.js just because it's smaller. If that doesn't work, I'll dump accounting.js.

Comment: I was beating my head aginst the wall while implementing a knockout autoNumeric binding on my own. Should have gone for copy& paste 2 hours before. Thanks man