# KnockoutJS autoNumeric binding handler replace empty value with 0

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Okay, so a user helped me yesterday get a very good implementation of a [numeric binding handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27369871/knockoutjs-intercept-to-one-decimal-place) written using autoNumeric, but I can't figure out how to get it to replace an empty string with 0. In the fiddle, delete the 20 then tab out and you can see that the resulting Integer Amount from knockout is NaN. It displays a 0, but the ko observable is clearly not updated behind the scenes. How can I get it to both display 0 and store 0 for an empty string?

html:

```
Integer Amount: <input type="text"  data-bind="autoNumeric:$data.Amount, settings:{mDec:0,aSep:','} " /><br />
Decimal Amount: <input type="text"  data-bind="autoNumeric:$data.OnloadAmount, settings:{mDec:3,aSep:'',vMin:0,vMax:1} " />
<p>Integer Amount:</p><p data-bind="text: Amount" />
```

javascript:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.autoNumeric = {
    init: function (el, valueAccessor, bindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    var $el = $(el),
        bindings = bindingsAccessor(),
        settings = bindings.settings,
        value = valueAccessor();

    $el.autoNumeric(settings);
    $el.autoNumeric('set', parseFloat(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value()), 10));
    $el.change(function () {
        value(parseFloat($el.autoNumeric('get'), 10));
    });
    },
    update: function (el, valueAccessor, bindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    var $el = $(el),
        newValue = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
        elementValue = $el.autoNumeric('get'),
        valueHasChanged = (newValue != elementValue);

    if ((newValue === 0) && (elementValue !== 0) && (elementValue !== "0")) {
        valueHasChanged = true;
    }

    if (valueHasChanged) {
        if (elementValue == '')
        $el.autoNumeric('set', 0);
        else
        $el.autoNumeric('set', newValue);
    }
    }
};

var vm = function(){   
    this.Amount=ko.observable(20); 
    this.OnloadAmount=ko.observable(0.5); //onLoad Testko.bindingHandlers.autoNumeric =  {
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sfortner/kLpxa544/5/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well you just need to write something like this to get it working

**In Update of binding handler :**

```
 if (valueHasChanged) {
      $el.autoNumeric('set', newValue);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $el.change()
      }, 0);
    }
```

Working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/vr9vqb3n/)**

Any issues let us know .