# KO binding is not working in IE10 and IE11

Tags: knockout.js, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

Here is my data-bind

```
<input type='text' data-bind="value: duration" id="duration" />
```

And I have custom javascript code to prevent user from submitting non-numeric text for "duration" which fires on keyup event for duration field.
This is working fine in chrome, firefox, and IE9. But not working in case of IE10 and IE11

Here is my script

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#duration', function () {
        var textvalue = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
        this.value = !textvalue ? '' : parseInt(textvalue, 10);
    });
```

Regards

Comment: its better to do in a ko way check this i answer one such question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27369871/knockoutjs-intercept-to-one-decimal-place/27372190#27372190 .

Comment: i made a fiddle check this http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/24566/ . let me know any concern  . cheers

Comment: Works for me in IE 11. But with this implementation I am not able to delete my input.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is a an old post now but in case other people come across this I had a similar issue today and discovered that there is another ko binding for text input called textInput. I would suggest using that instead. The textInput binding updates immediately as well as working fine for me in IE11.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html

```
<input type="text" data-bind="textInput: name" />
```

Also, jQuery has a nice numeric plugin for numeric inputs.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.Numeric/