# Custom or inbuilt binding for numeric type with specific precision in knockout

Tags: knockout.js

Is there a way to find inbuilt or custom binding in knockout that restrict user with some precision for numeric input?

For ex- 33.3 or 2002.3

Comment: well easy & elegant way with many options refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27369871/knockoutjs-intercept-to-one-decimal-place/27372190#27372190 . using Autonumeric js cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom binding..
This is an exmple is for `defaultPrecision: 1` but you can extend it for your need..

```
ko.bindingHandlers.numeric= {
    defaultPrecision: 1,
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        $(element).on("keydown", function (event) {
            // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
            if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 ||
                // Allow: Ctrl+A
                (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) ||
                // Allow: . ,
                (event.keyCode == 188 || event.keyCode == 190 || event.keyCode == 110) ||
                // Allow: home, end, left, right
                (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
                // let it happen, don't do anything
                return;
            }
            else {
                // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
                if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105)) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        });

        $(element).on("focusout", function (event) {
            var value: string = $(element).val(); //ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            if (value != undefined && value != '') {
                var formattedValue = parseFloat(value).toFixed(2); // Precision: 2
                $(element).val(formattedValue);
                ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, function () { return formattedValue; }, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
            }
        });
    },


};
```