# When using knockout validation, isValid reporting incorrectly when bound inside ko.foreach

Tags: javascript, validation, knockout.js

When using knockout.validation the isValid property will incorrectly report its status but only when it is "inside" a ko.foreach.

Using the code snippet below, if you run and enter the following values (q,z,10) in the same textbox,you will get the following output:

- self.InvoiceAmount is q and self.InvoiceAmount.isValid is true
- self.InvoiceAmount is z and self.InvoiceAmount.isValid is false
- self.InvoiceAmount is 10 and self.InvoiceAmount.isValid is false

As you can see, the validation rule is for a number and q should not report true as well as 10 should not report false.

It appears the order of execution is messed up because InvoiceAmount.subcribe is executed prior to InvoiceAmount.isValid.subscribe.

When the view model is just a simple property, the results are as expected:

- self.item is q and self.item.isValid is false
- self.item is z and self.item.isValid is false
- self.item is 10 and self.item.isValid is true

<del>Anyone know why this might be happening?</del>

---

**<Edit>**

*I'm really bad at asking the right question so I'll try to make it a little more clear what I'm after.  Sorry ;)*

I need to know if the value of the input is valid when **inside** the "subscribe" function of the observable that is bound to that input.

I am using the isValid value **inside** the subscribe function to determine if execution can continue (isValid is true) or if execution must stop (isValid is false).

When the input is bound to an observable inside a ko.foreach, the value of isValid is not updated until **AFTER** the subscribe function of the observable is executed.  This means that I am getting a stale value for isValid when I need to decide if execution can continue or if execution must stop.

**</Edit>**

---

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.numeral = {
            init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
                ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
            },
            update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
                var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
                    format = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().format) || ko.bindingHandlers.numeral.defaultFormat,
                    formattedValue = Number(value) ? numeral(value).format(format) : value;
                $(element).val(formattedValue);
            },
            defaultFormat: "0,0.00"
        };

        var viewModel = function(param) {

            var self = this;
          
            self.item = ko.observable().extend({ number: true });
            self.item.subscribe(function(value) {
                $("#log").append("<p>self.item is " + value + " and self.item.isValid is " + self.item.isValid() + "</p>");
            });

            self.items = ko.mapping.fromJS([]);

            ko.mapping.fromJS(param, {
                key: function(data) {
                    return data.CustomerId;
                },
                create: function(options) {
                    return new itemViewModel(options.data);
                }
            }, self.items);

        };

        var itemViewModel = function(item) {

            var self = this;

            ko.mapping.fromJS(item, {}, self);

            self.InvoiceAmount.extend({ number: true });

            self.InvoiceAmount.subscribe(function(value) {
                $("#log").append("<p>self.InvoiceAmount is " + value + " and self.InvoiceAmount.isValid is " + self.InvoiceAmount.isValid() + "</p>");
            });
        }

        $(function() {
            var vm = new viewModel([{ "InvoiceAmount": 10 }, { "InvoiceAmount": 20 }, { "InvoiceAmount": 30 }, { "InvoiceAmount": 40 }]);
            ko.applyBindings(vm);
        });
```

```css
.error {
  color: #FF0000;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/1.5.3/numeral.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout-validation/2.0.3/knockout.validation.js"></script>

<div>
  single item:<br/>
<input type="text" data-bind="numeral: item"/>
  </div>

<div>
  foreach:<br/>
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" data-bind="numeral: InvoiceAmount"/></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>

<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: i see something weird with numeric bindingHandlers i tried modifying with `autoNumeric` which i'm aware of it check here http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/27291/ . you can refer my answer on autonumeric here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27369871/knockoutjs-intercept-to-one-decimal-place/27372190#27372190

Comment: Without looking further into it, I'm guessing you could use the `.extend({ notify: always })` KO extender. This will make sure your subscribers are notified every time the value is accessed, even when it stays the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Completely revised reply:**

It is most likely a mistake to depend on the order of subscriptions. There are states of transition for a system of dependencies, during which the overall state is inconsistent. The system is designed to get to a consistent state, not to be in one at every instant.

A common trick to give the system time to reach a consistent state is to wrap a `setTimeout` around code that might otherwise be executed in mid-change. I've modified the code below to do that, and you can see that the reported states are correct.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.numeral = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
      format = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().format) || ko.bindingHandlers.numeral.defaultFormat,
      formattedValue = Number(value) ? numeral(value).format(format) : value;
    $(element).val(formattedValue);
  },
  defaultFormat: "0,0.00"
};

var viewModel = function(param) {

  var self = this;

  self.item = ko.observable().extend({
    number: true
  });
  self.item.subscribe(function(value) {
    $("#log").append("<p>self.item is " + value + " and self.item.isValid is " + self.item.isValid() + "</p>");
  });

  self.items = ko.mapping.fromJS([]);

  ko.mapping.fromJS(param, {
    key: function(data) {
      return data.CustomerId;
    },
    create: function(options) {
      return new itemViewModel(options.data);
    }
  }, self.items);

};

var itemViewModel = function(item) {

  var self = this;

  ko.mapping.fromJS(item, {}, self);

  self.InvoiceAmount.extend({
    number: true
  });

  self.InvoiceAmount.subscribe(function(value) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      $("#log").append("<p>self.InvoiceAmount is " + value + " and self.InvoiceAmount.isValid is " + self.InvoiceAmount.isValid() + "</p>");
      }, 0);
  });
}

$(function() {
  var vm = new viewModel([{
    "InvoiceAmount": 10
  }, {
    "InvoiceAmount": 20
  }, {
    "InvoiceAmount": 30
  }, {
    "InvoiceAmount": 40
  }]);
  ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

```css
.error {
  color: #FF0000;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/1.5.3/numeral.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout-validation/2.0.3/knockout.validation.js"></script>

<div>
  single item:
  <br/>
  <input type="text" data-bind="numeral: item" />
</div>

<div>
  foreach:
  <br/>
  <table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" data-bind="numeral: InvoiceAmount" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! I've been terrible at asking this question so I updated my post again. My log was an attempt to show that inside InvoiceAmount.subscribe, isValid is reporting the state for the previous value of InvoiceAmount. Your code appears to show the correct output in the log, but behind the scenes InvoiceAmount.subscribe is still being executed before isValid.subscribe but the UI is being updated too quickly to see that change. I'm more concerned with the *order* they are changing, subscription behavior when inside a ko.foreach is not the same as when not in a ko.foreach.

Comment: @Mike See if this answer doesn't work better for you.

Comment: That answer does work better for me, thank you so much!  One other (silly?) question regarding the solution.  Just wondering how a wait time of 0 would be enough time for the system to get to that consistent state?  Thanks again!

Comment: JavaScript isn't threaded, so when you setTimeout, it puts the task in a queue, even if the timeout is zero. Then it continues with whatever it's doing, and handling anything in the queue (like subscriptions).